# Android Studio documentation auto popup issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to `Android Studio IDE`. I was very accustomed to the Eclipse IDE and now everything seems hard to accomplish with Android Studio. One of the things which bothering me is the documentation auto popup in the settings. The popups are always overlapping the parameters info. which are important.

Does anybody know how to solve this or if it's possible at all to have the 2 options.

I've already tried changing the delays in the settings but the it's the same result.

Example image:
[image: Overlap]

Comment: +1, The popups are really annoying in android studio. They not only overlap in the program itself, but also sometimes is shown on other windows as well! :( I myself have completely turned them off and use F2 for documentation!

Comment: Yes sometimes overlaps other windows :( i will try your sugestion with the f2

Comment: If auto quick documentation is bypassed (as [@NightSkyLove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025411/nightskylove) suggests), you can view quick documentation if you hover over element and press CTRL + Q (Windows) / CTRL + J (MAC)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Go to **File** > **Settings** or do **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**S**
- Under **Editor** > **General**
- Uncheck **Show quick documentation on mouse move**

[image: Image of Settings and where to go]

Comment: Even better you can simply make delay to 2000ms. If there is error popup, documentation do not show. If no error popup, documentation popup after 2 sec. It's raisonably good delay.